# Norm of convex combination of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be elements of some normed vector space. Next, assume that $\|X\| < \|Y\|$. Does the following (strict) inequality $$ \|\alpha X + (1-\alpha)Y\| < \|Y\|$$ hold for $0 < \alpha < 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the triangle inequality and the homogeneity of norm:
$$\|\alpha X + (1-\alpha)Y\| \le \|\alpha X\| + \|(1-\alpha)Y\| = \alpha\|X\| + (1-\alpha)\|Y\| < \alpha\|Y\| + (1-\alpha)\|Y\| = \|Y\|.$$